# how to merge two columns in one column as date with pandas?

Tags: pandas, date, merge, format

I have a csv with the first column the date and the 5th the hours.
I would like to merge them in a single column with a specific format in order to write another csv file.

This is basically the file:

```py
DATE,DAY.WEEK,DUMMY.WEEKENDS.HOLIDAYS,DUMMY.MONDAY,HOUR 
01/01/2015,5,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
01/01/2015,5,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
01/01/2015,5,1,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
01/01/2015,5,1,0,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
01/01/2015,5,1,0,5,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
01/01/2015,5,1,0,6,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
01/01/2015,5,1,0,7,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
01/01/2015,5,1,0,8,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I have tried to read the dataframe as

```py
dataR = pd.read_csv(fnamecsv)
```

and convert the first line to date, as:

```py
date_dt3 = datetime.strptime(dataR["DATE"].iloc[0], '%d/%m/%Y')
```

However, this seems to me not the correct way for two reasons:

1) it add the hour without considering the hour column;

2) it seems not use the pandas feature.

Thanks for any kind of help,

Diedro

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameters `parse_dates` with list of both columns names and `date_parser` for specify format:

```
f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y %H')
dataR = pd.read_csv(fnamecsv, parse_dates=[['DATE','HOUR']], date_parser=f)
```

Or convert hours to timedeltas and add to datetimes later:

```
dataR = pd.read_csv(fnamecsv, parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True) 
dataR['DATE'] += pd.to_timedelta(dataR.pop('HOUR'), unit='H')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using + operator

you need to convert data frame elements into string before join. you can also use different separators during join, e.g. dash, underscore or space.

````
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Last': ['something', 'you', 'want'], 
                   'First': ['merge', 'with', 'this']}) 

print('Before Join') 
print(df, '\n') 

print('After join') 
df['Name']= df["First"].astype(str) +" "+ df["Last"] 
print(df) ```
````